# ng-websocket and ws: client sends successfully but doesn't receive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, websocket

My angularjs client websocketserver can properly send to the server, but when sending from server to client, the client doesn't register the event.

I'm using angular-websockets at the client side and ws at my express.js server

Here's my code.

server

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3002;
var server = http.createServer(app); // app = express
server.listen(port);
var socketComs = require('./lib/socketcoms').connect(server);    
var connect = function(server) {

      var wss = new WebSocketServer({
        server: server 
      });

      wss.on('connection', function(ws) {

        console.log("websocket connection open");

        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
          console.log('received', message); // THIS WORKS FINE
        });

        var id = setInterval(function() {
          ws.send('pong', 'data 123', function(err) {
            console.log('sent pong', err); // THIS IS NEVER CAUGHT BY CLIENT, err = clean

          });
        }, 2000); // Pong is never received

      });

    };
```

client

```
var connect = function() {
      ws.$on('$open', function() {
        console.log('wow its working');

        ws.$emit('message', 'some message');

      });

      ws.$on('pong', function(data) {
        console.log('yes', data);
      });

      ws.$on('$close', function(data) {
        console.log('wss closed');
      });
    };
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ng-websocket with PHP socket, and I have the same issue.
I just opened the ng-websocket.js and..guess what? the "ping" and "pong" events don't exist!
The "incoming" event is called "$message"...
This is how to get data from server:

```
ws.$on('$message', function (response) {
            console.log("DATA FROM SERVER", response);
```

Comment: I just learned that "pong" event was a custom event you send from server: at line 135 we have
`var decoded = JSON.parse(message.data);
me.$$fireEvent(decoded.event, decoded.data);`
So you can set the event property in your server response and then catch that from your controller
`ws.$on('customEvent', function (response) {
            console.log("DATA FROM SERVER", response);` Since it triggers two events, I decided to use the "$message" event and delete the custom one from ng-socket.js